# Whenever using development database in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I am using Whenever v0.9.7 with Rails 4.2.4. whenever is using development database in production also.

When i execute `whenever` i get following which shows production. But the time retrieved here is from development database and not production.

```
45 10 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /data/swati/Projects/metal && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''Mixins::UploadMaster.new.upload_data(ErpFile.find(4).table_name, ErpFile.find(4).file_name)'\'' >> /data/swati/Projects/metal/log/cron_log.log 2>&1'
```

Can anyone help resolve the issue?

Here is my schedule.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../environment', __FILE__)

set :output, ENV["CRON_LOG_FILE"]

erp_access = ErpAccess.first

erp_access.erp_files.each do |erp_file|
 if erp_file.start_time
  if erp_file.repeat_hours
   every erp_file.repeat_hours.hours, at: erp_file.start_time do
     toRun = 'Mixins::UploadMaster.new.upload_data(ErpFile.find(' + erp_file.id.to_s + ').table_name, ErpFile.find('+ erp_file.id.to_s + ').file_name)'
    runner toRun
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: I've never really used whenever, so I have no deep understanding of this gem. I quickly read the docs. Are you using capistrano? I found that if you are using different environments you should define them, or they might overwrite each other. set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
require "whenever/capistrano"

Comment: No I am not using capistrano. And as the above result of whenever command showing production environment. Doesn't that mean it is fetching correct environment?